# Excel - Include cell in column count if previous cell in row contains certain text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have searched for this but I have not had much luck. What I would like to do is below:

```
    A    B    C    D    E
1        ob        ob
2   ACR  ob           
3             ob       
4   ACR            ob 
5   ACR  ob

Total:   2         1
```

The `Total` row is just the column count, but I only want it to include the cells in the count that have `ACR` in the A column of that row.

So column B has a count of 2 even though there are 3 cells containing text, because only row 2 and 5 have `ACR` in the row.

Same with column D, only row 4 has `ACR` so only cell (D4) is being included in the count.

Is this possible using just a formula?

Comment: Intrigued by the downvote...

Comment: I'd guess it's because your question as it currently stands is "Is this possible using just a formula?", and on top of that you've shown us no research effort ("I have searched" doesn't count ;) ).  What have you tried so far?  Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: @techie007 Sorry I didn't realise this was the same as stackoverflow. I thought I could ask general questions on this site without showing working or what I have tried so far. Looking at some of the questions on here with up votes, and the description of this site on the tour page, I genuinely didn't think I needed to show what I have done so far... Sorry if I was wrong...

Comment: First, welcome to SU! :)  Please don't base your actions on crappy questions made by others, even if they got up-votes. Also avoid phrasing your problems as Yes/No questions (like "can I do this with just a formula?").  As for how to use the site; From the tour page (you may have to scroll down a little): "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. *Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.*".

Comment: @techie007 Thanks for the heads up :-)

Comment: No problem, and thank you for realizing I'm not just picking on you. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **countifs** function in the total row.  This will count all rows with ACR in column A and B not being blank.

```
=COUNTIFS($A1:$A7,"ACR",B1:B7,"<>")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'll have multiple values in Column A, just use a Pivot Table (if you've only got "ACR", then gtwebb's solution is quick and clean).

1. Convert your data to an Excel Table.
2. Create a Pivot Table from that Table, with

   - Row Labels = Column A
   - Values = Count Column B, Count Column C, Count Column D...

It should look like this:

[image: Count Text in Rows]

I added an additional Column A value (BCR) so you can see how it will update your Pivot Table.

Comment: ACR is the only value at the moment, but this is a great solution I hadn't thought of and will note for the future. I am going to use gtwebb's solution as is solves my issue very easily. Thanks for taking the time to answer.